# Header changing with group content

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

[image: Valid XHTML]

Hi, I currently have a report made in reportviewer and I have enabled groupings to be applied followed by a page break.

The groupings and the page break work perfectly, I can scroll to the next page and I can see a list corresponding to the next group.

The problem that I currently have is trying to make the Tablix's content above the grouping to display the current page grouped info. By default it always displays the first groupings info.

Second page picture below

[image: Valid XHTML]

As you can see the content didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data region that contains the "header" fields is not inside the grouping, then it will not change. It looks like you need to re-design the report so that the header and detail sections are inside the grouping. Consider using a List region, with the header and detail regions inside it and apply the grouping at the list level.

Comment: Hi @Nathan, thank you for taking your time to give me a very informative answer. It's greatly appreciated. You definitely pointed me in the right direction but I found that tablix nested inside a tabled was easier.